# resizing web page size according to clients resolution in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, css

i have developed a website and hosted it.. in the local system it is looking good..when i login from another system, it's looking very weird..

how to modify my page according to the client's resolution

can anyone help me out to solve this issue...plz

thnx 
navin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common mistakes is often use absolute sizes in pixels and em. Use more often percents: width: 90% and etc etc.

Comment: I don't think that using absolute sizes is a mistake. People with bigger screens typically expect to be able to see more information on them, not just see the same things displayed in a bigger font. Very few web sites will scale their own displays in proportional terms.  Besides you don't have any idea how big someones' screen is, only how big their window is.

Comment: jamietre, it's ok to set font size to absolute size, but what if you set width of main div to 500px? Then on bigger screen you get filled only part of screen, on smaller - scrolls.

Comment: Most sites set the width to something like 960 PX, which fits within a 1024 width screen (with browser borders). If your browser is wider, the extra space is blank, or used for ads. If narrower, then yes, it's hidden. See, for example, stackoverflow.com. It's nearly impossible to make a useful site layout that doesn't have some constraints on the dimensions.

Comment: thnx alot for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

> its looking very wierd..

there may be multiple reasons for that viz,

- browser
- browser version
- components used or framework
- css style compatibility

the optimum thing you can do is wrap your `entire page` or `master template` in a `div` and give `size` to that div. so that your site size may not differ in different `resolutions`.